# Use of __slots__ in an agent-based model written in Python

Tags: python, agent, agent-based-modeling

I am interested in building [agent-based models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent-based_model) of economic systems in Python. Typical model might have many thousands of agents (i.e., firms, consumers, etc).

Typical firm agent class might look something like:

```
class Firm(object):

    def __init__(capital, labor, productivity):
        self.capital = capital
        self.labor = labor
        self.productivity = productivity
```

In most of my models, attributes are not dynamically created and thus I could write the class using `__slots__`:

```
class Firm(object):
    __slots__ = ('capital', 'labor', 'productivity')

    def __init__(capital, labor, productivity):
        self.capital = capital
        self.labor = labor
        self.productivity = productivity
```

However, it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots?rq=1) that the use of `__slots__` is generally discouraged. I am wondering if this be a legitimate/advisable use case for `__slots__`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__slots__` feature is specifically meant to *save memory* when creating a large number of instances. Quoting the [`__slots__` documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots):

> By default, instances of both old and new-style classes have a dictionary for attribute storage. This wastes space for objects having very few instance variables. The space consumption can become acute when creating large numbers of instances.
>
> The default can be overridden by defining `__slots__` in a new-style class definition. The `__slots__` declaration takes a sequence of instance variables and reserves just enough space in each instance to hold a value for each variable. Space is saved because `__dict__` is not created for each instance.

Sounds like you are using slots for *exactly the right reasons*.

What is discouraged is to use `__slots__` for the no-dynamic-attributes side effect; you should use a metaclass for that instead.